# Matrix table in MS access

Tags: ms-access, database-design

Can I create a matrix table in access database. It looks like.

```
 Fat/SNF.           5. 6. 7.  8.  9.  10
    3.              0  2. 3. 6.  7.   9
    4.              2. 3. 5. 6.  8.  11
    5.              4. 5. 6. 8.  9.  13
    6.              5. 6. 9. 10. 11. 15
```

So that I can reference to find specific value in this matrix programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multidimensional array in VBA.

Here is the official MS documentation. It is for VB, but should also apply to VBA
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

If the content is static, you can create that matrix/array as a public variable or function in a modul for general use.

Comment: yes its static content. How can I create matrix/array as public variable or function in at module? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Yes I could, but it would go beyond the scope. Please do some research first and write another question if there is any problem. I suggest you google for these keywords: MS Access global variable, MS Access multidimensional arrays. There are tons of tutorials out there. Hope I could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to represent matrix data in MS Access tables.  If I had to do it, my first guess would be to store the data in triples, where one field specifies the row, another field specifies the column, and the third field specifies the value.

Then, I would build a query that presents a crosstabulated view of this data.

But it actually depends on your intended use of the matrix.